# The top Stiefel-Whitney Class of an Unorientable Manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

The top Stiefel-Whitney class of an orientable manifold is the Euler characteristic mod 2, since it is the mod 2 reduction of the Euler class. Does this still hold for an unorientable manifold?

Comment: The Euler class of (the tangent bundle of) a manifold only makes sense for an oriented manifold. So, does what still hold?

Comment: @Bill: the question "does the top Stiefel-Whitney class coincide with the Euler characteristic mod 2?" makes sense for any closed manifold.

Answer (score 14):

Every manifold is $Z_2$-orientable, so the Euler class (with $Z_2$-coefficients) is defined and coincides with the top Stiefel-Whitney class.

Back to your question: Yes, the top Stiefel-Whitney class evaluated on the fundamental class of the manifold is equal to the Euler characteristic mod 2 - regardless of the $Z$-orientability of the manifold.

This is Corollary 11.12 in *Milnor, Stasheff: Characteristic Classes*.